# Do Landings in a Simulator Count Towards Landing Currency? (FAA in the USA)

Tags: faa-regulations, currency

If a pilot is trying to complete 3 day or night landings every 90 days in a multi-engine aircraft in order to be multi-engine current per FAA requirements, can those landings be done in a Simulator or a Flight Training Device?

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8966/is-it-possible-to-log-ifr-currency-in-a-flight-simulator-without-an-instructor

Comment: An FTD? No... With a full motion sim that airlines use? I think it can, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Federico this question is more specific, and to be honest the answers in that question aren't great quality (just referring to an external source)... I'm tempted to leave this question open in hopes of a more complete answer

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, as long as the simulator is properly certified (to level B,C,or D) you can do your takeoffs and landings to regain currency.

Long haul airline pilots frequently have trouble staying current for 3 takeoffs and landings in 90 days. This is because it takes 4 pilots to complete a long haul flight but only 1 will get the takeoff and landing.

3 trips a month is about all you do, and if you are scheduled to be the augment pilot, you don't get a takeoff and landing.

Comment: According to this: http://d.pr/i/1aw7o it can be a level B, C, or D simulator. Thanks!

Comment: Good find. You are correct. I edited my answer to say B, C, or D. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

It can be done. As mentioned [here](https://www.nbaa.org/ops/safety/in-flight-safety/night/Part61-Sect61-57.php):

> (2) The takeoffs and landings required by paragraph (b)(1) of this
>   section may be accomplished in a flight simulator that is—
>
> (i) Approved by the Administrator for takeoffs and landings, if the
>   visual system is adjusted to represent the period described in
>   paragraph (b)(1) of this section; and
>
> (ii) Used in accordance with an approved course conducted by a
>   training center certificated under part 142 of this chapter.

The regulation is [14 CFR 61.57](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.57). For more details, you can read [this AC](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC%2061-98B.pdf).